# Problems Importing a .json file in PyCharm

Tags: python, json, pycharm

I have a main.py file and an OrientationData.json file in a PyCharm project. I would like to import my data into main.py, but for some reason it will not allow me to. I have json imported in main.py, and both files are in the same venv folder of the project. If I try to import a .py file into main.py, I have no issues, but it simply does not recognize the json file when I try to import it. 
[image]

*(.py imports working just fine)*
[image]

*(.json import not working)*

I have tried writing it as import OrientationData.json, but that also does not work. The specific error it's giving me is "no module named OrientationData" when I hover over the import statement. Why is this happening, and what can I do so that I can import and use my json data?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)
Include it as a [formatted code block](//stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) instead of an image.

Comment: Also, that's not how you read a json file. https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load

Comment: `import` is for Python modules. You can't use it to import JSON or any other kind of data. Look at the function `json.load`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that is the proper way to read a .json file in python. If you are trying to read the .json file for your code, try this:

```
f = open('OrientationData.json', 'r')
data = json.load(f)
```

God bless

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Import json
file=open('data.json',r)
data=json.load(file.read)

#remember to close your file at the end
#or use a with block